# Adminstrator change email content

Tags: email

Is it possible for a boss to change email content of a sent and read email?  If yes, can it be tracked by date modified and person that did the modification?

Answer (score 2):

This always depend on which side you're talking about. In the end it's pretty much like sending classic snail mail:

- If you're on the sender's end, there's nothing you can do to change an email once it's sent (since you'll always send a copy).
- If you're on the receiver's end, the copy in your inbox could be modified.
- Also, if you're a mail server that's passing the mail, you'd be able to modify it (this is what antivirus/antispam solutions typically will do).

If there are modifications, you can't necessarily track them. Only if the modifying entity explicitly marks changes or additions (like most antispam solutions, that will add their own header fields).

Of course, there are solutions to avoid or at least detect such modifications, by using digital signatures. Depending on their level (encrypting vs. signing), you can avoid others reading the content or at least detect modified content (unless the one changing got the proper signature files as well).